# std::priority_queue parameterised Comparison struct

Tags: c++, priority-queue

I am working with std::priority_queue for the first time for a University assignment. The assignment is a simulation of process scheduling. I would like to pass a parameter to my Comparison struct constructor to initialise and I thought I saw it on another forum, but I'm unable to find the source again. I looked on SO before posting but I didn't see anything similar.

Here is my priority_queue:

```
/* schedules.hpp / .cpp */
#include "process.hpp"

namespace my = procschedassignment;

int tick = 0;
std::priority_queue<my::Process, _
        std::vector<my::Process>,
        PrioritiseHighestResponseRatioNext(tick) > rq;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
line 100 - compiler errors are here
// ...
```

Here is my Comparison struct:

```
/* prioritise_process.hpp / .cpp */
#include "process.hpp"

namespace my = procschedassignment;

struct PrioritiseHighestResponseRatioNext {
    public:
        explicit PrioritiseHighestResponseRatioNext(int const& cpu_time)
                : cpu_time_(cpu_time) {};
        bool PrioritiseHighestResponseRatioNext::operator()(my::Process const& lhs,
                my::Process const& rhs) {
            bool ret;

            if (lhs.wait_time() > cpu_time_) {
                ret = (lhs.ResponseRatio() > rhs.ResponseRatio());
            } else if (rhs.wait_time() > cpu_time_) {
                ret = (lhs.ResponseRatio() < rhs.ResponseRatio());
            }

            return ret;
        };

    private:
        const int cpu_time_;
};
```

The compiler errors I get with this code are:

```
../src/schedules.cpp:100: error: ‘time’ cannot appear in a constant-expression
../src/schedules.cpp:100: error: template argument 3 is invalid
../src/schedules.cpp:100: error: invalid type in declaration before ‘;’ token
```

Is it possible to have a parameterised Comparison struct with std::priority_queue?
I am new to STL so I apologise that I don't have a better understanding of what's happening here.

Comment: Also note, `ret` variable is uninitialized and will has garbage value if `lhs.wait_time` is equal `cpu_time_` and `rgs.wait_time()`.

Comment: @fasked Yes, thanks :) I swear it's only dodgy as a result of rewriting some code blocks while trying to find a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to pass an object as template-parameter. This will not work. You should provide your comparator as argument to the constructor, and the type of the comparator as template-argument.

```
// declare type
typedef std::priority_queue<my::Process,
                            std::vector<my::Process>,
                            PrioritiseHighestResponseRatioNext > process_queue;
                            // ^^^ just a type, no object ^^^
// create object
process_queue rq(PrioritiseHighestResponseRatioNext(tick));
```

Comment: I see, but I would never have figured that on my own. At first I didn't understand what you did so I consulted http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/priority_queue/priority_queue/ , and I think it makes sense now. Very cool.